# WebSocket and CGI/FastCGI/SCGI protocols

Tags: cgi, comet, fastcgi, websocket, scgi

I'm looking for resources about interaction between client side web socket, web server and real application backend that works behind CGI, FastCGI or SCGI protocols.

It seems that this is impossible at this point as:

Request length is specifically defined in `CONTENT_LENGTH` variable so I can't expect
that the data would continue to come from web server from stdin, or may I? as unset `CONTENT_LEGTH` defines no-request body.

Application require to read `CONTENT_LEGTH` bytes of date no-more and if less are read then it is considered as disconnected client.

- Are there any resources on how (F|C)CGI is updated or can be used with WebSockets?
- Are there any drafts of SCGI/FCGI/CGI specks for WebSockets support?
- Are there any known web servers that support WebSockets?
- If so, do they support *CGI protocols for them?
- Have you had any experience with working with WebSockets and *CGI?

Thank you, all information would be appropriate.

Artyom

**Anybody?**

Comment: Syllable Web Server Cheyenne Gets WebSocket Framework ... see http://www.osnews.com/story/22681/Syllable_Web_Server_Cheyenne_Gets_WebSocket_Framework

Answer (score 5):

You can find a mod_websocket module for lighttpd [here](http://github.com/nori0428/mod_websocket). When building the module, be sure to specify the correct websocket protocol version you want to use (version -75 or -76). Starting with WebKit nightly build r59903 and Chrome 6.0.414.0 (r47952) only protocol version -76 is supported.

Note that with using WebSockets, you no longer need CGI, FastCGI or SCGI protocols for connecting the web server with the application back end. Just implement a TCP listener in your application (for mod_websocket to connect to) and use the socket for asynchronous I/O.

Comment: Interesting, but from what I can see it does not pass any HTTP Headers data like cookies etc to backend. So how should I manage sessions? I need to send such data explicitly instead of getting it from the web server.

Comment: Your websocket connections are created in the context of your HTTP session, you don't have to care about that. Beside that, HTTP and websocket are of course completely different protocols, so in your websocket connection you don't have access to HTTP headers.

Keep in mind that the websocket protocol only provides a minimal framing on top of TCP, so any application-specific data exchange between the application backend and the web client on top of a websocket connection you have to define and implement by yourself, just as you would do it using regular sockets.

Comment: Just for the record, AFAIK HTTP Headers are required fro several reasons: Know session data, know the URL is accessed, know the IP of remote host etc, etc, etc. So websocket is far from being just a socket.

Comment: Uh.. after the websocket handshake is done, it is really very much like regular sockets. Even Joe Armstrong (of Erlang fame) says so :)  http://armstrongonsoftware.blogspot.com/2009/12/comet-is-dead-long-live-websockets.html

Comment: After the handshake, yes. But the handshake itself is a valid HTTP request, and should arrive unmolested at the WebSocket server.RFC 6455[link](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-3) says a client may send other headers, such as cookies or authentication related headers. You are right though, you don't need SCGI or FCGI when using WebSocket, you should just speak WebSocket in your application. If something is acting as a proxy in between, it depends on the proxy how the original client address is forwarded. It might be stored in the "X-Forwarded-For" header.

Comment: You claim that they are similar after the handshake, but AFAIK TCP is stream-based, and WebSockets are message-based (to the end user application): https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3377406 Of course you can tunnel TCP over WebSockets, but that just means sticking together all WebSocket messages. So if your server only knows TCP, you may end up reinventing the wheel, since you may need messages.

Comment: ws is message based in that a little header is put on the front of each message of data you send but on the receiving side your websockets library should filter that out and give you effectively a stream